# Linear Programming Constraint Percentages

Tags: linear-programming

I have a homework about linear programming. I have to formulate the constraint of the following:

---

*A company produces two products, Deluxe and Special. The company decided that the Special must comprise at least 40 percent of the production total.*

---

I have attached my solution. Do you thing my solution is correct already? I just want to be sure if my answer is correct. I hope you can help me thank you.

[image: My solution for finding the constraint]

Answer (score 1):

Your solution seems fine.

Divide by $0.2$, it can be simplified to

$$-2x_1+3x_2 \ge 0$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!